# Calculate statistical distributions from a column in a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, statistics, row, distribution

I don't know if there is a specific method in VB.Net to calculate the statistical distribution from an array of values like the formula `Frequency()` in Excel. If not what is the easiest and fastest way of doing the same thing ?

For example I've a DataTable with my values in a Column called "Cement Deviation" :

```
Column Deviation
    0
   14
   11
    2
    6
    1
   16
   14
    5
   21
```

The bands in which I want to know the frequency of these values are :

- From minValue To -50 by Step of 10
- From -50 To -10 by Step of 5
- From -10 To -5 by Step of 1
- From -5 To -1 by Step of 0.5
- From -1 To -0.5 by Step of 0.1
- From -0.5 To -0.1 by Step of 0.05
- From -0.1 To 0.1 by Step of 0.01
- From 0.1 To 0.5 by Step of 0.05
- From 0.5 To 1 by Step of 0.1
- From 1 To 5 by Step of 0.5
- From 5 To 10 by Step of 1
- From 10 To 50 by Step of 5
- From 50 To maxValue by Step of 10

Can someone help me with it?

Thanks

Comment: So what is the problem, don't you know how to get a value from a DataRow or don't you know how to calculate a statistical distribution?

Comment: I know how to do both but I don't know if there isn't a better way than my example.

Comment: Yep for `row("Cement Deviation")` you're right I didn't paid attention to my example.

But how can I let the end-user choose for the classes instead of choosing them my self as 10 and 20?

Comment: What means "let the user choose for the classes"? Use variables instead of constant values. Can you show an example in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you calculate it since  my experiences with statistical distribution is limited and you haven't mentioned the way you want to calculate it.

However, this does at least compile:

```
Dim stat(2) As Integer
For Each row As DataRow In gridView.Rows
    Dim cementDeviation = row.Field(Of Int32)("Cement Deviation")
    Select Case cementDeviation 
        Case 0 To 10
            stat(0) += 1
        Case 10 To 20
            stat(1) += 1
    End Select
Next
```

In general there's nothing bad in looping the `DataRows` to calculate the values. But you should set `OPTION STRICT` to `on`, then your code would not compile  because `row("Cement Deviation")` is an object not integer. The good thing is that you are forced to use the correct types which prevents from nasty runtime errors.

**Edit** Here is an example how you could use dynamic ranges and count each class with LINQ. I have used a `DataTable` to store the min- and max-values but you could also use   a different in-memory collection like `List(Of CustomClass)` or even better - the database.

You can also simply loop the table but you wanted to see a different approach. I like LINQ since it can reduce complexitiy and increase readability:

The range table with sample data:

```
Dim rangeTable = New DataTable()
rangeTable.Columns.Add("Min", GetType(Int32))
rangeTable.Columns.Add("Max", GetType(Int32))
For i = 0 To 90 Step 10
    rangeTable.Rows.Add(i, i + 10)
Next
```

A single LINQ query to calculate all occurences for every range even ordered descending:

```
Dim stats =
    From rangeRow In rangeTable
    Let min = rangeRow.Field(Of Int32)("Min")
    Let max = rangeRow.Field(Of Int32)("Max")
    Select StatsInfo = New With {
        .Min = min, .Max = max,
        .Count = (From devRow In devTable
                  Let cementDeviation = devRow.Field(Of Int32)("Cement Deviation")
                  Where cementDeviation >= min AndAlso cementDeviation <= max).Count()
    }
    Order By StatsInfo.Count Descending
```

Output the result:

```
For Each stat In stats
    Console.WriteLine("Min: {0} Max: {1} Count: {2}", stat.Min, stat.Max, stat.Count)
Next
```

Note that i've renamed your `DataTable` to `devTable` since `gridView` is not a good name.

Comment: Ok my mistake... I'll give some more explanations :
First in a column I have some figures. For example : {0, 14, 11, 2, 6, 1, 16, 14, 5, 21}
Above in the question a made an example for statistical distribution (that you corrected for me... thanks) who counts how many times I have a value in the class 10 (from 0 to 10) and in the class 20 (from 10 to 20).
If there is no other way of counting how many values I have in each classes than by using a `Select Case` how can I then make the choice of the classes dynamically? For example instead of from 0 To 10, from 0 to 5 and from 5 to 10,...

Comment: @Rave: Normally you store this in a database, are you using one? It's still difficult to see the core problem of your question. You could for example use a  `List(Of CustomClass)` or a `DataTable` which contains all ranges. I'll try to give you an example later.

Comment: @Rave: Edited my answer to show an example how to use dynamic ranges.

Comment: I think it is what I was looking for but I can't try it before tomorrow. I'll edit my question to give more details and be clearer to those who may ask themselves the same question.